# Socket "cortando" bytes em dois pacotes

Tags: socket, actionscript-3, cliente-servidor

Estou desenvolvendo uma comunicação via Socket do meu programa com o servidor. Esse servidor é responsável por realizar uma ponte entre meu programa e os usuários que estão conectados a ele, ou seja, o usuário ao executar uma alteração no "programa A", o usuário do "programa B" irá receber essa alteração e aplicar as alterações automaticamente. A quantidade de programas conectados é indefinida. Abaixo um diagrama exemplificando:

[image: Onde em vermelho é o envio de bytes e em azul é o recebimento.]

*Onde em vermelho é o envio de bytes e em azul é o recebimento. A conexão entre o servidor e o cliente é única e não se fecha. Onde há duas setas de recebimento em azul, significa as duas alterações enviadas em vermelho.*

Tudo funciona corretamente. O problema surgiu quando fui enviar uma quantidade de bytes maior do que estava testando e percebi que o objeto Socket *"cortou"* o envio dos bytes para o servidor, separando-o em 2 pacotes, que, consequentemente, foi recebido em duas partes.

Acontece que esses bytes fazem parte de um único objeto JSON, e ao receber os pacotes, o evento `ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA` é despachado duas vezes, com a primeira e segunda parte do objeto JSON.

O código de envio é:

```
function enviar(json:Object):void {
    var str:String = JSON.stringify(json); // transformo json em string
    socket.writeUTFBytes(str); // escrevo a string no objeto socket
    socket.flush(); // faço o envio
}
```

Ao receber (Essa função é executada 2 vezes, "cortando" os bytes em dois pacotes):

```
function receber(e:ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA):void {
    var str:String = socket.readUTFBytes(socket.bytesAvailable); // transformo os bytes em string
    var json:Object = JSON.parse(str);
}
```

Há algum tipo de limitação de envio da quantidade de bytes? Devo realizar um gerenciamento de filas dos pacotes e separar por processos? Isso acontece em qualquer linguagem?

Comment: Caro biio, o limite de tamanho de pacotes existe em qualquer tipo de programação via Socket, o que ocorre é que muitas vezes é feito implicitamente e só é notado como no teu caso onde o pacote chega separadamente. Não conheço actionscript para te auxiliar quanto a isto mas sei que com sockets em C++ é necessário utilizar a API do sistema operacional para criar a socket e também para alterar o tamanho do pacote enviado e recebido. Espero que alguém consiga te ajudar mais especificamente.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O procedimento padrão (e necessário!) quando se faz programação em sockets é repetir a recepção até que se tenha recebido o número de bytes esperado.

Como é que se sabe o número de bytes a ser recebido ? Isso é responsabilidade da aplicação. Um método comum é colocar um header (cabeçalho) fixo no início de cada mensagem, contendo o tamanho da mensagem a seguir. O primeiro passo é a aplicação fazer a recepção deste header fixo. Mesmo neste passo é necessário eventualmente fazer recepções repetidas. Após a recepção deste header fixo, a aplicação sabe o tamanho da mensagem a seguir, e portanto faz recepções repetidas até receber o total de bytes da mensagem.

A necessidade desse procedimento advém do fato de que o protocolo TCP transmite e recebe bytes, não mensagens. Assim, quando uma aplicação faz um send de 300 bytes não existe nenhuma garantia de que no outro lado esta mensagem chegue em um único pedaço de 300 bytes. Teoricamente, a mensagem pode chegar em 3 pedaços de 100 bytes, por exemplo, isto é permitido pelo protocolo TCP. Com mensagens pequenas normalmente a cada send corresponde um receive do outro lado, mas à medida que se aumenta o tamanho das mensagens aumenta também a probabilidade de que elas cheguem em vários pedaços do outro lado.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Já havia tentando algo parecido, mas vou tentar explicar melhor: um dos problemas que provavelmente irei enfrentar é quando a aplicação possuir mais de uma alteração sendo enviada via Socket pelo servidor. O servidor estará enviando duas alterações paralelas simultaneamente para a aplicação, divididas em vários pacotes com bytes em quantidades indefinidas. Como posso colocar o _header_ no começo do começo das alterações e saber que os pacotes com os bytes restantes são da primeira ou segunda alteração? A aplicação iria se perder, não iria?

Comment: @biio Se for o mesmo socket em TCP, não são paralelas, são sempre sequenciais. Se está abrindo várias conexões, de qq forma tb não vão se misturar os pacotes (e provavelmente algo está estranho na aplicação, pois normalmente se usa o mesmo canal pra comunicação toda). Se vai muitiplexar dados intercalando num stream, continua sendo responsabilidade da aplicação como vai marcar cada bloco. O importante é que em TCP, se você mandar 5000 bytes e a carga for dividida em 3 partes, as 3 partes chegarão na sequência original, então não tem muito com que se preocupar.

Comment: @biio sua "tarefa" é ir lendo os dados num buffer. Quando der o numero de bytes do header, pegue estes bytes e consuma na aplicação. **Importante:** se você leu a quantidade indicada no header e sobraram bytes, **mantenha** esta sobra no buffer, pois faz parte da  próxima mensagem que está chegando.

Comment: @Bacco, desculpa insistir. Eu estou quase entendendo ou talvez seja minhas explicações que estão um pouco confusas, rsrs. O meu cliente recebe os dados das alterações do servidor, e este é responsável por receber as alterações de outros clientes. Essas alterações são enviadas por uma única conexão socket, ou seja, na mesma conexão eu posso estar recebendo do servidor (Que recebe de outros clientes) **n** alterações. Se as alterações forem enviadas paralelas, porém em fila, ambos os pacotes de bytes são recebidos em fila também?

Comment: @Bacco, fiz uma alteração na pergunta com uma imagem exemplificando o que eu quero dizer, rsrs.

Comment: @biio a alteração feita não muda em nada o que foi respondido e o que eu comentei, é simplesmente isso que o JoséX disse. De qualquer forma, pra cada cliente vai ser uma conexão diferente, e em cada conexão, os bytes não mudam de ordem. Essa é uma das diferenças entre TCP e UDP, por exemplo. Em TCP, o que for enviado, vai ser recebido na mesma ordem. Só sugiro tomar um cuidado nas próximas perguntas que fizer no site para por todos os detalhes já de início, pois uma alteração substancial pode invalidar as respostas já dadas. No caso atual, não faz diferença, mas é bom evitar.

Comment: @biio Só uma observação extra: não confunda a conexão com o listener. Normalmente um listener pode "ouvir" vários clientes, mas uma vez iniciada, cada conexão é independente.