# Socket entre C++ e C#

Tags: c#, c++, socket

Estou enfrentando um problema.

Tenho o código do server feito em C++, rodando no ubuntu.

E tenho o código do cliente feito em C#, rodando no windows.

No código feito no server (C++) me deparei com um problema

```
//recebe tamanho arquivo
read(idSockfd, tmpBuffer, BUFSIZ_SOCKET); 
int file_size = atoi(tmpBuffer);
bzero(tmpBuffer,BUFSIZ_SOCKET);

//recebe outra instrucao
read(idSockfd, tmpBuffer, BUFSIZ_SOCKET);
```

Isto funcionava quando eu mandava a requisição do meu computador (Windows 10), porém em outros computadores como Windows 7 o "segundo" `read`, passava direto, como se tivesse mandado algo no buffer.
Para resolver esse problema, após uma pesquisa encontrei a seguinte solução:

Passando o parâmetro `MSG_WAITALL`, isto resolveu o problema. Em todos os computadores testados funcionou..

```
recv(idSockfd, tmpBuffer, BUFSIZ_SOCKET, MSG_WAITALL);
```

Entretando tenho uma função que recebe arquivos

```
FILE* received_file = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "w");
if (received_file == NULL)
{
    printf("Erro ao receber o arquivo\n");
}
bzero(tmpBuffer,BUFSIZ_SOCKET);
int remain_data = file_size;
int len;
while (((len = recv(idSockfd, tmpBuffer, BUFSIZ_SOCKET, MSG_WAITALL)) > 0) && (remain_data > 0))
{
        fwrite(tmpBuffer, sizeof(char), len, received_file);
        remain_data -= len;
        fprintf(stdout, "Recebendo %d bytes e falta:- %d bytes\n", len, remain_data);
}

printf("Fechando arquivo\n");
fclose(received_file);
```

Acontece que a "última" parte do arquivo, sempre vai ser menor do que o tamanho do buffer, e com a instrução MSG_WAITWALL, fica esperando todo o buffer, e nunca recebe os últimos bytes do arquivo.

Tentei alterar para o seguinte maneira também

```
(((len = recv(idSockfd, tmpBuffer, BUFSIZ_SOCKET, 0)) > 0) && (remain_data > 0))
(((len = recv(idSockfd, tmpBuffer, BUFSIZ_SOCKET, 0)) > MSG_TRUNC) && (remain_data > 0))
(((len = recv(idSockfd, tmpBuffer, BUFSIZ_SOCKET, 0)) > MSG_PEEK) && (remain_data > 0))
(((len = recv(idSockfd, tmpBuffer, BUFSIZ_SOCKET, 0)) > MSG_PEEK | MSG_TRUNC) && (remain_data > 0))
```

porém todas minhas tentativas foram frustradas.

Segue  o código do C# que faz o envio do arquivo..

```
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
               SocketType.Stream,
               ProtocolType.Tcp);


s.Connect(conn.Ip, conn.Port);

buffer = new byte[102400];

//envia o lenght
byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(new FileInfo(f.FileName).Length.ToString());
byData.CopyTo(buffer, 0);
debug = s.Send(buffer);

//envia o caminho
byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(path);
byData.CopyTo(buffer, 0);
debug = s.Send(buffer);

//envia o arquivo
s.SendFile(f.FileName);
```

Como posso fazer para ter uma garantia do que recebe é o que o aplicação client mandou e não alguma "sujeira", digo "sujeira" pois nos computadores testados com o windows 7, recebe uns bytes que sinceramente não sei da onde saiu.

Obrigado pela atenção e ajuda desde já.

Comment: Esse processamento é síncrono? Ao invés do MSG_WAITALL poderia usar um pattern tipo monitor ou semaforo para controle das threads?

Comment: Originalmente é uma `thread`, mas realizei testes nas função main, e acontece o mesmo problema..

Comment: eu achei sua descrição do problema um  pouco confusa...veja se a resposta que eu dei a [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147458/socket-cortando-bytes-em-dois-pacotes/149273#149273) ajuda...o que posso dizer é que nunca precisei usar esse flag MSG_WAITALL, e esse flag realmente vai causar o problema que você relatou por último, de a aplicação ficar parada esperando receber **todos** os BUFSIZ_SOCKET bytes

Comment: @JoséX. Obrigado pela resposta.. Vou testar, mas provavelmente é isto que estava ocorrendo, como você escreveu na resposta 300 bytes podem chegar em 3 partes de 100 bytes. Obrigado.

Comment: O correto seria você ter um estado de espera de arquivo e outro adquirindo o arquivo por exemplo. Dê read em 1 byte até você ter conseguido ler 4 bytes. Com esses 4 bytes, você tem o tamanho do arquivo. Vá lendo de 1 em 1 assim como fez com o tamanho e concatenando o buffer. Pelo menos dessa forma nunca tive problemas de pacotes pela metade ou algo como foi relatado