# Como pegar o buffer vindo do socket?

Tags: c, socket

Estou recebendo um quantidade de dados vindo de um servidor, o cliente(o código a baixo), após o envio de uma mensagem, ele recebe outra, mas gostaria de saber o tamanho da mensagem que esta chegando do servidor para alocar a variável antes de passar para o `recv` **(supondo que o servidor envie tamanhos aleatórios de texto)**.

- Existe alguma função para recolher o tamanho do **Buffer** vindo pelo *Socket*?
- É possível pegar o tamanho dos dados vindo do *Socket* por `fstat` ou `fseek`?
- Como posso fazer essa implementação?

**`client.c`**

```
/*Socket and Network headers*/
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PORT 8000
#define TCP 6

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int _sock;
    int res;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv; //socket address struct
    struct hostent *server;

    // int socket(sin_family, socket_type, protocol)
    // protocol TCP equal 6 (TRANSMISSION CONTROL PROTOCOL)
    _sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, TCP);
    if(_sock < 0)
        return 1;

    server = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");

    // set zero in buffer
    bzero( (char *) &serv, sizeof(serv));

    // configure connection
    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    bcopy((char *) server->h_addr,
            (char *) &serv.sin_addr.s_addr,
            server->h_length);
    //serv.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int len = sizeof(serv);
    res = connect(_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv, len);

    if(res < 0)
        return 2;

    bzero(buffer, 256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    res = write(_sock,buffer, strlen(buffer));

    int size;
    ioctl(_sock, FIONREAD, &size);
    printf("%d\n", size);

    char c;
    while(1)
        if(read(_sock, &c, 1) != 1)
            break;
        else
            printf("%c",c);
    //  res = read(_sock, buffer, 255);
    //if(res)
    //  puts(buffer);
    //strcpy(buffer,"return message.");

    close(_sock);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível usar a função `ioctl` (no Windows, `ioctlsocket`) com argumento FIONREAD, para obter a informação que você quer, mas **nunca** vi isso ser usado. Entre outras coisas, porque quando você fizer o `recv` o valor retornado pelo ioctl já poderá ser outro (por exemplo, se os dados estão chegando continuamente por uma conexão). Este é um exemplo típico do anti-pattern TOCTOU (ver no Google, Wikipedia, etc).

Sua maneira de tentar usar sockets está invertida em relação ao modo comumente utilizado. Este modo é o seguinte: você tem um buffer de tamanho X, e usa este buffer para fazer leituras repetidas.

Veja minha resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/149273/54255)          a uma pergunta sobre sockets, talvez seja útil.

Answer (score 5):

Você esta querendo prever o tamanho de um **stream** desconhecido para pré alocar um buffer? Isso não existe.

- Supondo que você pode formatar a mensagem no servidor você poderia
  acrescentar logo no começo um Header com o tamanho do restante da
  mensagem. Procedimento comum em arquivos. Mas se a conexão falhar
  terás problemas com a função read() que é bloqueante.
- Se você não pode formatar a mensagem terá que lidar com buffers grandes ou
  realocação de buffer e é melhor pensar em trabalhar com threads e timeout ao
  ler sockets.

Answer (score 3):

Uma resposta que eu vi no StackOverflow em inglês sobre [porque `while(!eof(fd))` é errado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) cabe aqui. Vou tentar adaptar aqui, e responder: "Porque você não deve contar com o tamanho da 'mensagem', mesmo que o sistema operacional ofereça essa funcionalidade?"

A princípio, considere essa análise em alto nível de abstração:

#### Concorrência e Simultaneidade

Operações de I/O interagem com o ambiente. O ambiente não é parte do seu programa, e não está sob seu controle. O ambiente existe *concorrentemente* ao seu programa. Como todas as coisas concorrentes, perguntas sobre um estado atual absoluto não fazem sentido: o conceito de "simultaneidade" não existe absolutamente, como já dizia Einstein com sua relatividade geral, e Leslie Lamport, ao [tentar estabelecer a relação de ordem entre eventos que acontecem concorrentemente em um sistema distribuído](http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/time-clocks.pdf).

Sendo mais preciso: suponha que você pergunte, "qual o tamanho da mensagem?". Você poderia perguntar isso para uma outra thread concorrente recebendo a mensagem, ou para o sistema de I/O. Mas a resposta é inerentemente, pois se a thread disser "200 bytes", na hora que você for ler, pode ser que a quantidade tenha dobrado. Não importa qual tamanho seja reportado pelo sistema, essa informação sempre poderá ter mudado no momento que você fizer a leitura da mensagem, então a utilidade dessa informação é limitada.

De fato, não é razoável perguntar ao sistema de I/O como se dará, no futuro, uma operação de I/O. A única maneira razoável de tratar a questão é tentando realizar a operação, para então tratar as possíveis consequências da operação. No momento que você interage com o ambiente, e somente nesse momento, você consegue descobrir como a operação transcorreria, efetivamente realizando aquela operação.

#### Sockets

Quanto do ambiente concorrente externo a interface de socket realmente expõe ao programador? Depende do protocolo. Socket é uma interface abstrata que dá acesso a várias protocolos de comunicação diferentes. Teoricamente, é possível que um protocolo trate todas os percalços internamente à implementação do socket, e possibilite o recebimento mensagens inteiras (supondo também que as mensagens inteiras caibam no buffer). Talvez o UDP permita esse tratamento, considerando que seus datagramas têm tamanho máximo de 65507 bytes, o que cabe nos buffers de rede.

Mas seu código não usa UDP. Usa TCP, e ao contrário do UDP, não é orientado a mensagens, mas orientado a `stream`. Não existem limites lógicos entre as unidades de comunicação dentro do TCP, e um byte está potencialmente disponível para o usuário do socket assim que chega na interface de rede. Portanto todas as incertezas de se comunicar com o mundo exterior são repassadas diretamente ao programa.

A maneira correta de se ler um socket TCP é alocar a estrutura lógica que o seu programa espera, e ler o socket em um loop até que ela seja preenchida. Por exemplo:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool read_full(int fd, void *buf, size_t size)
{
    uint8_t *ptr = buf;
    ssize_t ret;
    while(size > 0) {
        ret = read(fd, ptr, size);
        if(ret <= 0) {
            if(errno == EINTR)
                continue;

            return false;
        }
        size -= ret;
        ptr += ret;
    }

    return true;
}

void func(int fd)
{
    struct my_msg msg;

    if(read_full(fd, &msg, sizeof msg)) {
        puts("Mensagem recebida com sucesso!");

        /* Use msg... */
    } else {
        puts("Falha ao receber a mensagem.\n"
            "Poderia verificar errno para descobrir o que aconteceu.");
    }
}
```

Se você não sabe o tamanho de uma unidade lógica de mensagem, isso deve ser tratado pelo protocolo da sua aplicação (por exemplo, cada mensagem poderia ter um cabeçalho de tamanho fixo contendo o tamanho do resto da mensagem, deste modo, a primeira coisa que você tentaria receber é este cabeçalho). O TCP não tem essa informação! A informação que você consegue com `ioctl(_sock, FIONREAD, &size);` não serve para nada em uma comunicação TCP, pois cada mensagem enviada pelo servidor pode ter sido dividida em vários datagramas pelas camada TCP, e a informação do tamanho original não é preservada pela rede. O que você consegue com essa chamada é o tamanho do próximo datagrama pendente, que não é necessariamente igual ao tamanho da mensagem enviada pela outra ponta.