# Como identificar o anti-padrão TOCTOU? Como evitá-lo/removê-lo?

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, condição-de-corrida

Estava eu lendo uma resposta sobre [transformar vetores em lista em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/360230/64969), quando nos comentário o [AR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) me direciona para os códigos fonte da JDK9. [Lá nos fontes](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/8645b4aed22f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ImmutableCollections.java#l229), deparo-me com o seguinte comentário:

```
ListN(E... input) {
  // copy and check manually to avoid TOCTOU

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  E[] tmp = (E[])new Object[input.length]; // implicit nullcheck of input
  for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    tmp[i] = Objects.requireNonNull(input[i]);
  }
  this.elements = tmp;
}
```

Então, me veio a dúvida "o que é TOCTOU"? A referência que tem aqui no SOpt é [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/192715/64969) (para a query [`?q=toctou`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=toctou) em 2019-02-04 antes das 9h GMT-3).

O [@Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss) me apontou o significado: hora de checagem/hora de uso (*time of check to time of use*, do original em inglês). Ele acontece quando você checa os dados em um momento e, na hora de usar os dados pra valer, o sistema está em um estado diferente e que, portanto, torna a checagem inválida.

Então, fiquei me questionando:

- como identificar que caí neste anti-padrão?
- tem algum padrão para evitar cair neste anti-padrão?
- se eu pegar um código que identifiquei que está com TOCTOU, tem algum algoritmo para que eu altere o código de modo a removê-lo?

Comment: Também fiquei com essa dúvida quando li o código  fonte, e até ia fazer essa pergunta aqui, mas vc foi mais rápido :)

Comment: Hahahaha! Rapidez no gatilho =D EU _quase_ que te pergunto sobre isso, mas aí percebi que fugia demais da resposta original

Comment: Praticamente duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101

Comment: @Maniero de fato. O TOCTOU é uma condição de corrida (acho que um tipo específico de). Identificar um TOCTOU, então, é identificar condições de corrida que alterem o valor interno de um programa depois de verificarem seu estado. Aqui, esperava ver uma resposta falando de IPC e de multi-thread; e para IPC, esperava uma resposta voltada a tratar no lado remoto a verificação e alteração do valor interno de modo atômico. Vou ver com mais carinho essa questão da condição de corrida para poder fechar esta questão aqui quando acabar a bounty

Comment: Se lhe interessar posso colocar um exemplo que acabou de ocorrer em código comercial cujo o objeto é a intercomunicação de variáveis entre escopos distribuídos entre diferentes AppDomains?

Answer (score 18):

**TOCTOU** é acrônimo para **T**ime **O**f **C**heck to **T**ime **O**f **U**se. É um *bug* do tipo [condição de corrida](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_corrida) causado entre a checagem de uma condição e a utilização dos resultados da checagem.

Quantos as suas questões:

> Como identificar que caí neste [anti-padrão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/575315/o-que-%C3%A9-um-anti-pattern)?

A maioria dos códigos que fazem acesso ao sistema de arquivos em baixo nível estão comprometidos com TOCTOU e alguns são vulneráveis a ataque.

Código em C aparentemente inocente mas que está vulnerável ao TOCTOU:

```c
// access retorna 0 em caso de sucesso
if(!access(file, W_OK)) {
   f = fopen(file, "wb+");
   write_to_file(f);
} else {
   fprintf(stderr, "Permissão negada ao abrir o arquivo %s.\n", file);
}
```

Como explorar o TOCTOU da linha de comando.

```
$ touch dummy; ln –s dummy pointer
$ rm pointer; ln –s /etc/passwd pointer
```

Nesse caso é um ataque fictício da linha de comando para obter as credenciais locais de um arquivo local. No computador pessoal isso não é tão preocupante, em redes corporativas isso é um problema, mas no caso de um CGI escrito em baixo nível e que faça acesso ao sistema de arquivos pode comprometer um servidor inteiro.

> Tem algum padrão para evitar cair neste anti-padrão?

Evite fazer acessos a arquivos de sistema em baixo nível. Ao invés de usar um mecanismo de checagem use tratamento de exceções e se tiver em ambiente Windows ou Mono use File Handlers para acessar o sistema de arquivos.

Em Java (ou outra linguagem de alto nível) a vulnerabilidade ao TOCTOU não pode ser explorada por terceiros, porém pode congelar uma aplicação (deadlock) como é caso do exemplo dos vetores caso a função em questão seja acessado por dois ou mais threads. Então em código multithreading use `lock` e `syncrhonize` nos trechos em houver concorrência e **ao invés da checagem de uma condição, force um tratamento de erro**.

Evite coisas como:

```cs
if (file is null) {
  // Menssagem de erro
} else {
  // realize acões com o arquivo
}
```

E prefira:

```cs
try
  file.Open("")
  // realize ações com o arquivo
  ...
catch (){
  // Mensagem de erro
}
```

> Se eu pegar um código que identifiquei que está com TOCTOU, tem algum
> algoritmo para que eu altere o código de modo a removê-lo?

Transforme a checagem em um tratamento de erro e aplique mecanismos de sincronização que a linguagem oferecer.

Comment: Da uma lida no item 9
[RaceConditions.pdf](https://www.auto.tuwien.ac.at/~chris/teaching/slides/RaceConditions.pdf)