# Pra tratar erros sempre devo usar try catch?

Tags: python, if, validação, exceção, try-catch

As vezes quando sei que algo pode falhar no meu sistema eu faço uma validação utilizando `if`, igual está abaixo:

```
lista = [1,2,3]
#um número que esteja entre os indices da lista
numero = int(input(f'Digite um número entre 0 e {len(lista)-1}: '))
#se o número for maior ou menor que os indices da lita
if numero > len(lista)-1 or numero < 0:
    print('Algo deu errado')
else:
    #se der certo
    print(lista[numero])
```

Porém, eu também posso usar o `try except` para tratar/pegar os erros. Exemplo:

```
lista = [1,2,3]
#um número que esteja entre os indices da lista
numero = int(input(f'Digite um número entre 0 e {len(lista)-1}: '))
try:
    #se der certo
    print(lista[numero])
except:
    print('Algo deu errado.')
```

Qual dessas maneiras de tratar os erros é melhor ou mais recomendada?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Há controvérsias. Depende do que deseja e do estilo que adotar. A comunidade Python prefere o chamado [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html?highlight=eafp#term-eafp) em vez de [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html?highlight=eafp#term-lbyl) ([referência](https://diveintopython3.net/your-first-python-program.html#exceptions)). Claro que tem que analisar cada caso, mas faz sentido para o tipo de linguagem.

Eu acho que isso um pouco abusivo, mas é como a linguagem definiu que deve comunicar problemas em certas situações. Então se você fizer mais ou menos assim está correto nesta linguagem. Mas mesmo nela pode haver abuso demais. Algumas pessoas começa usar exceção pra tudo, até quando não deveria, mesmo no estilo *pythonico*.

Algumas pessoas vão começar usar exceção onde um `if` funciona tão bem ou melhor. Para mim o seu código inicial está mais certo para fazer essa validação.  Me parece que no caso do seu código não faz sentido usar a exceção no lugar do `if`. Me parece que é o caso do seu código, mas não dá pra cravar qual é mais certo.

O segundo é mais lento que o primeiro se der erro, mas o primeiro pode ser mais lento se não der. Para um código simples assim não faz a menor diferença, mas é bom saber disso, em algo com um laço e milhões de dados pode dar uma boa diferença, depende se os dados são mais errados ou mais certos. Teria que medir.

Eu acho o primeiro mais semântico, você mostra que se importa especificamente com aquilo antes de dar o erro. Mas ainda é legível o segundo código.

Na verdade o segundo código não é tão bom, mas porque ele foi mal escrito. Bem escrito a legibilidade muda pouco. Alguns dirão que até o segundo ficaria mais expressivo. Ficaria assim:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3]
numero = int(input(f'Digite um número entre 0 e {len(lista)-1}: '))
try:
    print(lista[numero])
except IndexError:
    print('O número digitado está fora da faixa aceita')
```

Capturar **qualquer** exceção é um erro mesmo que funcione, porque até outro tipo de erro que não é o que você está preparado para tratar ali cairia no `except`. O que faria os códigos não serem equivalentes já que o primeiro é bem específico e o segundo trata qualquer erro.

Inclusive no primeiro código a mensagem deveria ser mais específica, não muda o resultado final mas deixa sua aplicação melhor.

Já disse que eu não gosto de tratar validação como exceção e pode pesquisar no site pra ver que falo disso em muitas postagens. Mas em Python acho menos problemático por ser uma linguagem de *script*.

Há u mdetalhe extra: se a pessoa digitar uma letra dá erro nos dois casos.

Dá um pouco mais de trabalho lidar com todo tipo de problema da primeira forma, a não ser que você crie uma função que faça isso e a chame sempre no lugar do `input()` o que muita gente faz. Havia uma época que era uma das primeiras coisas que um programador faria quando aprende programar. Hoje como em geral as pessoas só aprendem seguir receitas de bolo e não usam a criatividade, não pensam sobre como solucionar algo de um jeito melhor, mesmo que dê um pouco mais de trabalho, mas seja uma solução mais adequada.

Pode ficar como exercício, melhor que muita coisa que pedem para fazer por aí porque não é só codificar, é pensar no problema, achar uma solução completa e genérica, tem que ser bem desenhada.

Mas realmente dá menos trabalho na linguagem deixar a exceção estourar e tratar porque ela não tem boas ferramentas para tratar antes do erro acontecer.

E tratar se digitou um número é bem mais complicado de fazer (eu faria, mas não estou recomendando para todos).

Algo assim parece melhor para a maioria dos *pythonistas*:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3]
try:
    numero = int(input(f'Digite um número entre 0 e {len(lista)-1}: '))
    print(lista[numero])
except ValueError:
    print('Não foi digitado um número')
except IndexError:
    print('O número digitado está fora da faixa aceita')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xUm5eP). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ginuthxh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Exception.py).

Eu acho que você deve usar o que achar melhor, mas deve ser consistência. Então mesmo que seja difícil e tenha que criar uma biblioteca para lidar com isso, se vai validar antes de dar o erro, deve fazer em tudo, não pode usar exceção para verificar se o dado é um dos caracteres que espera e usar condição para verificar se está dentro da faixa requerida. Claro, pode, mas é esquisito. Ambos não são casos excepcionais, por isso a exceção não é boa, mas se opta pela exceção faça em ambos. Dado inválido e algo excepcional que aconteceu são coisas diferentes.

Comment: Não sei porque, mas eu acho que essa resposta deixou alguns pythonistas envergonhados kkk

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 não conheço muito a comunidade então não entendi a piada, pode explicar?

Comment: Indiretamente você meio que chamou os Pythonistas de desleixados por usarem `try-except` pra tudo kkk. Sei que não foi a intenção mas é o que parece na resposta e eu sinceramente concordo com isso. Python realmente da muita liberdade e muitos programadores acabam abusando dessa liberdade.

Comment: Não é desleixo porque foi escolhido conscientemente fazer isso. Eles acham bom assim. Pelo menos há muito conteúdo citando isso. Desleixo seria fazer qualquer coisa sem pensar. Ter uma opção que eu não concordo não é o mesmo que aceitar qualquer opção. Mas eu acho oque há inconsistência, e isso meio que vale para qualquer comunidade que acha que exceção deve ser usada para validação, e é um dos motivos que deveria ser mais claro o que é validação e o que é caso excepcional.

Answer (score 2):

A melhor maneira de tratar erros é se certificar de que não haverá erros. O recomendado é usar o bloco `try-except` apenas quando você não tem controle de algo que possa possivelmente gerar uma exceção ou então quando a verificação for muito extensa e compense mais deixar o erro acontecer para capturar a exceção.

No seu código por exemplo, existe um caso em que você pode utilizar uma condicional e um outro caso onde você pode utilizar o `try-except` para capturar uma exceção.

Na primeira parte do código, você recebe a entrada do usuário esperando que seja numérica. Mas você já pensou sobre o que aconteceria caso o usuário não digitasse um número e sim uma letra?

É nesse tipo de situação em que você deve utilizar o bloco `try` já que nesse caso, verificar se o dado é numérico ou não daria muito mais trabalho do que capturar a exceção.

```
try:
    entrada = input(f'Digite um número entre 0 e {len(lista)-1}: ')
    numero = int(entrada)
except:
    print("Você deve digitar um valor numérico.")
    numero = -1
```

Já na segunda parte do código, não é necessário utilizar o `try` porque você pode muito bem com uma simples condicional verificar o valor que o usuário digitou.

```
if 0 < numero < len(lista):
    print(lista[numero])
else:
    print("Algo de errado não está certo =/")
```

---

Veja também este outro exemplo. No código abaixo, a função recebe um texto e retorna um dicionário esperando que o texto seja um JSON.

Mas como poderíamos verificar se o texto está realmente correto? Neste caso, é muito melhor utilizar um `try-except` para estar pronto para capturar uma eventual exceção no código.

```
def get_json_from(text):

    try: return json.loads(text)
    except: return None
```

Comment: Não se usa `if` para fazer a verificação ou não da existência de um arquivo. Você expõe o seu código a uma condição de corrida chamada TocTou(Time Of Check to Time Of Use) que ocorre quando no código é verificada a existência do arquivo mas um evento externo ao código remove o arquivo logo após a verificação isso permite o seu código ser explorado maliciosamente. Leia [Como identificar o anti-padrão TOCTOU? Como evitá-lo/removê-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/361869/137387)

Comment: Ok, vou trocar o exemplo e ler esse artigo sobre o TT.

Answer (score 0):

Em relação ao comando em si "try-catch" independente da linguagem de programação adotada e baseado em minha experiência pessoal ao descobrir e aplicar esse comando em minhas lógicas, recomendo sua utilização quando você quiser executar um bloco de ações. Por exemplo em métodos que devem ser executados sequencialmente, em que a execução de um depende do resultado retornado do anterior. Dessa forma dentro do try você coloca todo o procedimento a ser realizado em caso de sucesso de todas as ações e no bloco catch você apenas retornará a exceção encontrada sem precisar saber exatamente de onde foi lançada a exceção.

Para isso você deve em todos os seus métodos chamados dentro do bloco try lançar uma exceção (throw Exception) quando ocorrer algum comportamento inesperado com a mensagem que descreve o erro identificado e código se for necessário, ao identificar alguma exceção o bloco try será interrompido imediatamente e o que estiver no catch será executado, protegendo os comandos que a partir dali existiam dentro do try. 
Além desses benefícios é nítido que o código fica mais organizado dessa forma, separando todo o comportamento esperado (try) do comportamento inesperado (catch). No seu caso, não vejo problema em utilizar o if-else.

Obs: me desculpe por não dar exemplos com Python por não possuir experiência com a linguagem, porém achei que essa dúvida poderia ser respondida de uma maneira geral, relacionado a programação.