# Como converter a seguinte string em uma lista: string1 = '"Sobrenome, nome", 10, 15, 30' em lista = ['Sobrenome, nome', '10', '15', '30']

Tags: python, string, lista

Não posso usar as funções do csv, nem nenhuma biblioteca do python.
Toda vez que eu tento fica, 
`lista = ['Sobrenome', 'nome', '10', '15', '30']`

Usei os comandos:

```
string1 = '"Sobrenome, nome", 10, 15, 30'
lista = [item.strip().strip('"') for item in string1.split(",")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Para analisar uma string de cujo o conteúdo contenha um literal Python use a função [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```python
from ast import literal_eval

s = '"Sobrenome, nome", 10, 15, 30'

print(list( literal_eval(s) ))
#['Sobrenome, nome', 10, 15, 30]
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/5LZMGw)</sup>

#### Explicação:

Em python tupla se consiste em uma sequência de valores separados por vírgulas podendo ou não estar cercada por parêntesis `()`.

> Conforme a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) tuplas podem ser construídas de várias
> maneiras:
>
> - Usando um par de parênteses para denotar a tupla vazia: `()`.
> - Usando uma vírgula à direita para uma tupla singleton: `a,` ou `(a,)`.
> - Separando os itens com vírgulas: `a, b, c` ou `(a, b, c)`.
> - Usando a função embutida `tuple()` ou `tuple(iterable)`.

Já a função `ast.literal_eval()` consome uma string constituída apenas nas seguintes estruturas literais do Python: `strings`, `bytes`, `números`, `tuplas`, `listas`, `dicionários`, `sets`, `booleanos`, `None` e `Ellipsis`.
Ao contrário da função embutida [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#eval) a função `ast.literal_eval()`não executar código Python.

No caso a string `'"Sobrenome, nome", 10, 15, 30'` pode se interpretada como uma tupla a se analisada com `ast.literal_eval()` e convertida em lista com a função embutida [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#func-list)

### `ast.literal_eval()` não está livre de problemas!

Mesmo `ast.literal_eval()` sendo projetado especificamente para não executar código Python e de não haver possiblidade de inferir ou pesquisar módulos ou identificadores, e de de não ter capacidade de executar código, `ast.literal_eval()` não está livre de problemas, entradas mal formadas podem lançar as seguintes exceções:

- [ValueError](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError)
- [TypeError](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError)
- [SyntaxError](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/exceptions.html#SyntaxError)
- [MemoryError](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/exceptions.html#MemoryError)
- [RecursionError](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/exceptions.html#RecursionError)

Sendo prudente usar `ast.literal_eval()` aninhado em um [bloco de tratamento de erros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/451936/137387).

Answer (score -1):

Existe um módulo built-in que faz isso, o shlex.

```
import shlex

string1 = '"Sobrenome, nome", 10, 15, 30'
lista = [x.strip(',') for x in shlex.split(string1)]
print(lista)
```