# Não consigo adicionar inteiros em um arquivo java

Tags: java, arquivo

Não estou conseguindo adicionar inteiros em um arquivo `.txt` em Java. Não consigo entender o que estou fazendo de errado. Como por exemplo adicionar esse número 10 do codigo abaixo. Gostaria de saber, como faço para adicionar o inteiro?

```
public static void salvar(){
    File arq = new File("C:\\Users\\giova\\Documents\\arq.txt");
    
    try{
        if (!arq.exists()) {
            arq.createNewFile();
        }
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    
    FileWriter fw;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(arq, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(10);
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, `FileWriter` já cria o arquivo caso ele não exista, então não precisa verificar isso antes. Aliás, verificar se o arquivo existe para só depois criá-lo pode cair em uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/112052) (ver mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/360272/112052)). Em vez disso, simplesmente tente criar o `FileWriter` e trate as exceções que ele lança caso o arquivo não possa ser criado.

E a partir do Java 7 você pode usar o [*try-with-resoruces*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/112052), que garante que o arquivo é fechado ao final (mesmo em caso de erro).

E quanto ao `write`, veja na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write(int)) que o número que você passa é o código numérico equivalente ao [code point](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052) do caractere. No caso, valores menores que 128 correspondem à [tabela ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/), e o número 10 equivale ao caractere [NEW LINE (ou LINE FEED)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a/index.htm), também conhecido como a "quebra de linha".

Se você quer escrever o número `10`, terá que escrever os caracteres `1` e `0` explicitamente, como `char` ou então `String`:

```java
// try-with-resources
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("nomeArquivo.txt", true))) {
    bw.write(Integer.toString(10));
    // ou ainda
    // bw.write("10");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // tratar erros (coloque aqui o seu código de tratamento de erro)
}
// não precisa chamar close(), o bloco try-with-resources já faz isso automaticamente
```

Assim, ele escreve os caracteres `1` e `0`, em vez do NEW LINE.

E no código acima, ele cai no `catch` caso o arquivo não possa ser criado (por exemplo, por falta de permissão ou disco cheio), e também em caso de erros na escrita. E o bloco *try-with-resources* garante que ele é fechado ao final, sem precisar chamar `close` explicitamente.

---

Outra alternativa é usar um [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html), pois esta classe sim possui um método que aceita um inteiro diretamente:

```java
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("nomeArquivo.txt", true)))) {
    pw.print(10); // escreve o número 10 no arquivo
} catch (IOException e) {
    // tratar erros
}
```

E você também pode usar as classes do [pacote `java.nio`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/package-summary.html), como `java.nio.file.Files` e `java.nio.file.Paths`. Mas neste caso ele também não aceita o número 10 diretamente:

```java
// não esqueça de colocar em um bloco try-catch
Files.write(Paths.get("nomeArquivo.txt"), "10".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```