# Como fazer uma função retorna o valor que está no arquivo (c++ e fstream)

Tags: c++, arquivo

estou tentado aprende a usar a biblioteca fstream do c++, mas acabei tendo a dificuldade de usar em uma função fora da main(), quando eu rodo o código ele não retorna nada

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string ler_arquivo(string arquivo){
  fstream ler_arquivo;
  string texto;

  ler_arquivo.open("texte.txt",fstream::in);
  
  if(ler_arquivo.is_open()){
    while(!ler_arquivo.eof()){
      getline(ler_arquivo, texto);
    }
  }else{
    texto = "erro na leitura do arquivo \n";
  }
  ler_arquivo.close();
  return texto;
}

int main() {
  fstream arquivo;  //recebe o aarquivo
  string linha;
  //vector<double> num;

  linha = ler_arquivo("texte.txt");
  
  cout << linha;
return 0;
}
```

pelo teste que fiz o código entra na função e no if e o loop do while normalmente, mas acaba retornando nada

(obs.: o arquivo tem algumas frases como exemplo, mas é só como afim de estuda de como funciona)

(obs.2: a string recebe tudo o que está no arquivo)

Comment: declare uma auxiliar fora do primeiro escopo  do `for` ...    `string auxiliar` abaixo do `getline`  atribua a ela o  **texto** `aux+=texto;`  em vez de `return texto;`  retorne como `return aux;`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
string ler_arquivo(string arquivo){
  fstream ler_arquivo;
  string texto;

  ler_arquivo.open("texte.txt",fstream::in);
  
  if(ler_arquivo.is_open()){
    while(!ler_arquivo.eof()){
      getline(ler_arquivo, texto);
    }
  }else{
    texto = "erro na leitura do arquivo \n";
  }
  ler_arquivo.close();
  return texto;
}
```

Então `ler_arquivo()` deveria receber o nome do arquivo e retornar uma `string`. Mas a julgar pelo código que escreveu esperava retornar o conteúdo do arquivo todo? Em uma `string` só? Uma vez só?

E declarou

```
    fstream ler_arquivo;
```

dentro da função de mesmo nome. Confuso. E não usou `arquivo` em lugar nenhum. Então é melhor repensar.

O exemplo abaixo retorna a primeira linha do arquivo se ele for aberto com sucesso. Pode comparar com o modo que usou e talvez ajude.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string ler_arquivo(string arquivo)
{
    ifstream entrada{arquivo};
    string texto = "erro na leitura do arquivo \n";
    if (not entrada.is_open()) return texto;
    std::getline(entrada, texto,'\n');
    return texto;
}

int main()
{
    auto linha = ler_arquivo("teste.txt");
    cout << linha << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eu não o negativei, mas tenho certeza do motivo dos negativos.  Aqui `if (not entrada.is_open())` jamais oriente a fazem isso, em C/C++ e linguagens de baixo nível quando faz esse teste e em seguida tenta ler/escrever um arquivo você embute no seu programa uma vulnerabilidade a ser explorada chamada TOCTOU que permite ao atacante de baixa credencial tomar o controle do OS.  Nesses casos em C emule o tratamento de erros com setjmp/longjmp e em C++ use um tratamento de erros. Em linguagens médio e alto nível explorar o TOCTOU apenas congela o thread onde foi inserida a vulnerabilidade.

Comment: [Como identificar o anti-padrão TOCTOU? Como evitá-lo/removê-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360272/como-identificar-o-anti-padr%c3%a3o-toctou-como-evit%c3%a1-lo-remov%c3%aa-lo/361869?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C55.5581#361869)

Comment: Os comentários se estenderam e o excesso de ruído foi removido **(** após intervalo suficiente para notificação e leitura **)**, conforme sinalização da comunidade - foram mantidos os que tem relação direta com o conteúdo dos posts. (este aqui também será removido em algum tempo, é apenas um feedback sobre a remoção dos anteriores para evitar mal entendido). Para discurtir o funcionamento do site, critérios de voto, escopo e qualquer ponto que trate do funcionamento da comunidade podem usar o site [meta].